# Cannot import svg.js in Typescript

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, svg.js, parceljs

I installed svg.js as a dev dependency. It appears in my package.json as `svg.js": "^2.6.6"`.

I can import the library in a javascript file with:

```
import SVG from 'svg.js';
```

However, if I do the same thing in a Typescript file, I get the error: "cannot find module svg.js".

I also have a folder called "typings" with the type definition file available on the svg.js website.

Why can't I use this library?

Comment: `svg.js` provides typings out-of-the-box. You don't need extra ones in a `typings` folder. Have you run `npm install`/`yarn install`?

Comment: i have the same problem, the lib is installed, i can console.log(SVG) and sees the methods of the libary, but i cant use it in my code in cause of typescript need to know the types

Answer (score 0):

in ES6, you can import it using this code:

```js
import * as SVG from "svg.js";
let draw = SVG('drawing');
let rect = draw.rect(100, 100);
```

Comment: Does this really solve the issue? Because I don't really see any types (such as `SVGLineElement` or the likes) there... Will I be able to use this in e.g. an Angular application along with type-safety?